# Render Lightning component as pdf

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

Can we render lightning component as pdf without using visualforce page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You will have to use VF page and embed it in lightning component. There are few external libraries available but they will most likely get blocked due to security issues.